# NullPointerException by ActivityResult, Facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, nullpointerexception

**Hi. I want add facebook sdk to my app for authorization/login. I register my app, testing - all work, until I add permission (for email), and now I cath NullPointerException - code:**

```
private void startFacebookLogin() {

    Session.StatusCallback mCallback = new Session.StatusCallback()  {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                        Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onCompleted()");

                        final GraphUser graphUser = user;
                        if (user != null) {
                            final Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, AboutYourselfActivity.class);

                            intent.putExtra(NAME, graphUser.getName());
                            intent.putExtra(EMAIL, (String) graphUser.asMap().get(EMAIL));
                            intent.putExtra(USER_SOCIAL_ID, graphUser.getId());
                            intent.putExtra(PROVIDER, FACEBOOK);
                            intent.putExtra(PASSWORD, "");
                            intent.putExtra(PHONE, "");

                            Log.d("FACEBOOK USER ", graphUser.getName());
                            Log.d("FACEBOOK USER ", graphUser.getId());
                            Log.d("FACEBOOK USER ",(String) graphUser.asMap().get(EMAIL));
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            //RegisterActivity.this.finish();

                            URL img_value = null;
                            try {
                                img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.getId() + "/picture?type=small");
                                BitmapLoaderTask task = new BitmapLoaderTask(new DownloadComplete() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void complete() {

                                    }
                                });
                                task.execute(img_value);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            } else {
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "hmm " + session.getState().toString());

            }
        }
    };

    Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(RegisterActivity.this);
    request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday"));
    request.setCallback(mCallback );


    // get active session
    Session mFacebookSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (mFacebookSession == null || mFacebookSession.isClosed())
    {
        mFacebookSession = new Session(RegisterActivity.this);
    }
    mFacebookSession.openForRead(request);
```

}

**Here i have crash**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data); // here I cath crash
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3406)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3449)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RegisterActivity.onActivityResult(RegisterActivity.java:300)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5456)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3402)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3449)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you print out which each variable is? looks like one of those four parameters is null. do you know which one is?

Comment: I think this is the data

Comment: Its possible that you are trying to get data that isn't available because you are requesting data thats not in     request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday"));. i.e image, try to add "basic_profile" in the permissions.

Comment: added "basic_profile" - don't work

Comment: sorry, my bad. try "public_profile"

Comment: i check this - Session.getActiveSession() == null. Why?

Comment: check my answer, its because you haven't established a session. so you need to check if the session is open first or not null, and if it isn't null then do whatever you have to do, otherwise you need to request a session.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you men for help. Now all work, code:

```
    private static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI, Session.StatusCallback callback, List<String> permissions) {
    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setPermissions(permissions).setCallback(callback);
    Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build();
    if (SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI) {
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(openRequest);
        return session;
    }
    return null;
}

private void startFacebookLogin() {

    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissions.add("email");

    //start Facebook session
    openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                //make request to the /me API
                Log.e("sessionOpened", "true");
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                            String lastName = user.getLastName();
                            String id = user.getId();
                            String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();

                            final Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, AboutYourselfActivity.class);

                            intent.putExtra(NAME, user.getName());
                            intent.putExtra(EMAIL, user.getProperty("email").toString());
                            intent.putExtra(USER_SOCIAL_ID,user.getId());
                            intent.putExtra(PROVIDER, FACEBOOK);
                            intent.putExtra(PASSWORD, "");
                            intent.putExtra(PHONE, "");

                            DatabaseManager.getInstance(RegisterActivity.this).
                                    setProperty(FACEBOOK_USER_NAME, user.getName());
                            DatabaseManager.getInstance(RegisterActivity.this).
                                    setProperty(FACEBOOK_USER_EMAIL, user.getProperty("email").toString());
                            DatabaseManager.getInstance(RegisterActivity.this).
                                    setProperty(FACEBOOK_USER_ID, user.getId());



                            Log.e("facebookId", id);
                            Log.e("firstName", firstName);
                            Log.e("lastName", lastName);
                            Log.e("email", email);
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();

            }
        }
    }, permissions);
```

Comment: still NullPointerException :(

Answer (score 2):

```
try this
    private void performFacebookLogin()
    {
        Log.d("FACEBOOK", "performFacebookLogin");
        final Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("email"));
        Session openActiveSession = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
            {
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "call");
                if (session.isOpened() && !isFetching)
                {
                    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "if (session.isOpened() && !isFetching)");
                    isFetching = true;
                    session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                    Request getMe = Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                        {
                            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onCompleted");
                            if (user != null)
                            {
                                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "user != null");
                                org.json.JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                                String email = graphResponse.optString("email");
                                String id = graphResponse.optString("id");
                                //String facebookName = user.getUsername();
                                System.out.println("Birthday--------------"+user.getBirthday());
                                System.out.println("User ID----------------"+user.getId());
                                System.out.println("LINK---------------------"+user.getLink());
                                System.out.println("username---------------"+user.getUsername());
                                System.out.println("Hashcode----------------"+user.hashCode());
                                System.out.println("Inner JSON--------------"+user.getInnerJSONObject());
                                System.out.println("Location-------------------"+user.getLocation());
                                System.out.println("class------------------------"+user.getClass());
                                System.out.println(user.getProperty("email"));


                                if (email == null || email.length() < 0)
                                {
                                    System.out.println(
                                            "Facebook Login"+
                                                    "An email address is required for your account, we could" +
                                            " not find an email associated with this Facebook account. Please associate a email with this account or login the oldskool way.");

                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    getMe.executeAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!session.isOpened())
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK", "!session.isOpened()");
                    else
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK", "isFetching");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thks for a response, but where get this variable isFetching? http://joxi.ru/lMvoU4wyTJDjAtVlU9U

Comment: boolean isFetching = false

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_birthday", "email");
Session session = Session.openActiveSession(this, false, permissions, statusCallback);
if(session == null) {
    session = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, permissions, statusCallback);
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    //Log.e("session2 ", "session " + session.getAccessToken());

    if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) v.getContext()).setCallback(statusCallback));
    }
}
else
{
    //DO WHATEVER YOU HAVE TO DO Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken() should exist
}


private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // Respond to session state changes, ex: updating the view
        Log.e("session", "session " + session.getAccessToken() + "   state: " + state.isOpened());
    }
}
```

Sorry, create a public instance variable:

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
```

Comment: with arguments in method

Comment: which method? you have to be a little more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

*I used this code and now authorization is worked*

```
List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("email");
        permissions.add("user_photos");

        //start Facebook session
        openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    //make request to the /me API
                    Log.e("sessionOpened", "true");
                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                // Work with user (get name, email and other)
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();

                }
            }
        }, permissions);
```